# How to use asp.net simplemembership in xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, .net, rest, xamarin, simplemembership

I have already built a MVC website in .net I want to know if its possible to access the relevant information exposed through the controllers (REST)? The issue here is that in my website I use simplemembership to be able to access the controllers. How can I bluid an iOS app in xamarin that can access these controllers (REST) with this kind of authorization / authentication?

Comment: Yes you can, but I think if you have a choice you should go for Identity as Simple Membership is not a token based one and lacks customization.

Comment: I already have everything implemented with simple membership and since the website is not on a server i can access directly i can only access the information the controllers via rest can provide if i can access the through simple membership. doesn't xamarin provide any easy way to do this?